# HTML5 Canvas rotate in Google Chrome - Terrible rendering

Tags: html, canvas, rotation, angle

When a photo is displayed on a HTML5 canvas element, and is rotated, the result looks fine in FireFox but terrible in Chrome. It seems as if Google Chrome does not know how to smooth the rotated edges.

For an example take a look at http://www.ernestdelgado.com/public-tests/canvasphoto/demo/canvas.html
Make one of the photos big and have it rotated slightly around its center. Turn on the 'simple mode' so that the photo gets a white border for maximum contrast. You will now see that the edges of the photo are anything but smooth. In FireFox the result is much better!

Does anyone know if this problem can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chrome team has been breaking and unbreaking anti-aliasing of different parts of Canvas for a year and a half now.

Lots of bugs crop up with the same problem: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7508

Unfortunately, waiting is your only recourse here, unless you want to make an anti-alias effect yourself, which is possible but a lot of work for something that "should" look consistent

Comment: Also thanks for pointing out the term for this (anti-aliasing) which I wasn't familiar with.